# Android - Storing data without a database

Tags: android

My application records user movement with Geofence boundaries, if the user exits the Geofence, alerts are appropriately escalated. These alert are counted and displayed in a summary at the end of the activity. However I would like to create a stats page where it displays the last week or month of activities as well as the number of alerts so that I can display these in a chart. Is there anyway to do this effectively without using a database?

I had thought of writing data to a log file and reading it but curious as to if there is a better option.

Comment: `A better option` would be... **using a database**.

Comment: What is stopping you from implementing a database? This sound like exactly what a database would be for

Comment: android offers many possibilities to store data. It depends on the data you want to save, how you should save it. The following article may be an interesting read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: @Vyger I agree, however I am on a tight schedule and my database skills leave alot to be desired. Although I will look into it to see if I could implement it quickly enough.

Comment: sqllite databases are really easy on Android

Comment: I encourage you to, so to give you the opportunity of **making things** with the data: sorting, grouping, averaging, counting, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences but it will require a lot of controls, probably more then creating a database. If you insist not to use a database, put an integer to your shared preferences saving the count of your data, also that integer will become your id. Then you can store your data with a loop depending on your data.

Here is to write your data to shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyStoredData",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        private SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor = mSharedPrefs.edit();

        int count = mSharedPrefs.getInt("storedDataCount", 0);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < yourCurrentDataCount ; i++) {
            mPrefsEditor.putInt("data" + count, yourData.get(i));
            count++;
        }
        mPrefsEditor.putInt("storedDataCount", count);
```

And to get your data,

```
int count = mSharedPrefs.getInt("storedDataCount", 0);
for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
            yourData.add(mSharedPrefs.getString("data" + i, "defaultData"));
            count++;
        }
```

Edit: 
I should have added some explaining. The idea is to save the count of your data to generate an id, and save the tag according to it. This code will work like this, lets say you have 5 strings. Since you don't have a MyStoredData xml, it will get created. Then since you don't have the "storedDataCount" tag, you will get 0 as a count. Your loop will iterate 5 times and in each iteration, you will add a tag to your xml like "<.data0>your first data<./data0><.data1>your second data <./data1>... After your loop is done, you will modify your storedDataCount and it will become <.storedDataCount>5<./ storedDataCount>. And the next time you use your app, your count will start from 5 so your tag will start from <.data5>. For reading, you will iterate through tags by checking "data0", "data1" and so on.

Comment: Thank you, would it be possible to use this for this scenario: On a Monday there are 5 alerts, Tuesday 4 alerts so I would implement a bar chart to show the dates against number of alerts. What I mean is it possible to detect the number of alerts to a certain date?

Comment: Well if that's the case, you don't need to save your count and generate an identifier. Since you are working with the dates and they are already unique, you can just give your tag name as the date.

Comment: I am stuck on how to retrieve the values using date as the tag...any ideas?

Comment: Yes, if you save them as epoch, you will have problems since you can't traverse on saved epoch times, they are way too unique. What you can do is saving them with more specific dates like, if you save your data daily, save the epoch of, lets say, 2014.03.19.0.0.0 meaning 00.AM. This way you will make sure your next data will be on 2014.03.20.0.0.0 so you can convert to epoch and retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java serialization if you dont want to use database.
You can also use [XML](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html)/[JSON](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html) for storing data.

Answer (score 0):

I support already mentioned favoritism towards using a DB for this task. Nevertheless, if I were to do it via FS, I would use a transactional async library like Square's [**tape**](http://square.github.io/tape/) is.

In your case I would keep the data during a session in JSON object (structure) and persist it (in `onPause()`) and restore it (in `onRestore()`) with [**tape**](http://square.github.io/tape/)'s GSON Object Converter.

Should be easy out of the box, I believe.

Tape website: http://square.github.io/tape/

**Alternatively** to manually persisting a file or using a 3rd party library like tape, you could always (de)serialize your JSON to `SharedPreferences`.